# CSS column layout issue only on Mac OS Safari

Tags: macos, css, layout, safari

I'm having an issue with a WordPress/WooCommerce site that I'm working on, whereby there is a problem with the grid layout of the products displayed on the website homepage. Screenshot below:

[image]

The correct display should look like this (Windows Chrome browser):

[image]

The display issue only occurs when viewing the site with Safari on Mac OS. However, I don't own a Mac so I'm unable to test this.

Other than going into a Currys store and using my mobile hotspot I'm pretty stuck. Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing this and possibly provide me with some CSS code to fix?

The website can be seen here: http://chickenguard.kinsta.com/

Comment: Can you elaborate on the bug? I'm guessing the problem occurs when you do that hover effect that makes the image bigger, but that's just a guess. Show a picture with the correct display too, and the step by step to reproduce it and where to look.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly when it occurs as I don't have a Mac to see for myself, but the first screenshot shows the broken display. I've attached a screenshot showing how it should look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the error in Safari on a 1400px wide screen. And I found the cause for it: There is this CSS rule in the stylesheet:

```
.woocommerce.products-listing-grid .products.products-loop-column-3 > .product, 
.woocommerce.products-listing-grid .products.products-loop-column-3 > .product.last {
    width: 32%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

If I deactivate the `width: 32%;` in that rule, `width` becomes 31.9% (defined in the `.woocommerce .products.products-loop-column-3 > .product` rule), and the whole page / the grid of products looks correct, like in the other browsers.

So I guess you should either erase that width setting from that rule or create another rule which overwrites it.

Comment: I've amended the CSS now and I will have to wait for confirmation that this is fixed for my client. However, it does affect the total width on other browsers so that the grid now doesn't quite span the whole width of the container. If my client is happy, though, I'm happy and I'll come back and accept your answer as it's barely noticeable.

Comment: This does fix the layout on Mac Safari but it also affect the total width of the columns as mentioned above. I also had to apply this fix in an `@media` query to prevent it from affecting the column layouts on smaller screen sizes on PC.